# Recognizing attributes type, when working with properties

Tags: python, properties, attributes, inspect

**Example situation:**

So, lets assume I'm creating some inspection tool, and I wanna have a methods for listing callable fields, which are some methods, for listing data fields (normal attributes) and properties (so I can also add information on which descriptor methods are declared, to see if attribute is constant, etc).

**Questions:**

1. How do I iterate over some objects fields?
2. How do I recognise whether some field is property? (Checking whether it is callable is easy, with `callable` builtin function, just trying to call some object, or checking whether it has `__call__` attribute; those ways of checking are listed from most to least reliable and safe)

**Known approaches:**

*Ad. 1*

Easiest way I can think of is using `dir()` or checking `__slots__`. Still, I know that `dir()` is intended to be used in REPL mode only, but I dont know why, so here's some bonus question: *"Why shouldn't I use `dir()` in real-life usage? Or should I?"*.

Also, I think I remember something about `__dict__`, but I'd have to consult [Data model](http://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html) to be sure how to use it, and if it would do what I need. Anyway, I'd also have to consult that article when trying to use `__slots__`.

*Ad. 2*

No freaking idea. I tried using plain `getattr(obj, name)`, `object.__getattribute__(obj, name)`, `obj.__getattribute__(name)`, `obj.__getattr__(name)` (for some cases only) to get descriptor object (one that implements `__get__`, `__set__`, etc) and check for those methods, but instead, `obj.name.__get__(...)` is called.

**Post Scriptum**

This isn't real-life example, more like my way of figuring out nuances of python. If there is some reason why I shouldn't even try to do it, I'll be glad to hear it, but I will also like to know how to do it, if I REALLY (like "I know that is bad, but if I won't do it, my boss will fire me"-really) need to.

I'm mostly interested in p3.3+, but those question stand for p2.7.x too.

**== EDIT ==**

*Ad. 2*

With help from [user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112) I got this:

```
>>> class A:
...     @property
...     def x(self):
...         return 1
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.x
1
>>> isinstance(a.x, int)
True
>>> isinstance(a.x, property)
False
>>> isinstance(type(a).x, property)
True
```

Comment: "How do I recognise whether some field is property?" - `isinstance(Class.prop, property)`.

Comment: Wow, it was too easy to expect. Thanks a lot! Edited, to contain answer for (2)

Comment: Although, since you'll be working with field names determined at runtime, it'll look more like `isinstance(getattr(Class, propname), property)`.

Comment: True, but I considered it obvious ;) Thanks.